# How do I give a non-admin user permission to post certain data in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, middleware

In my nodejs app, I have several tables, such as bus-table, location-table, trip-table, and booking-table.

Some, such as bus, trip, and location, are only accessible to administrators.

And one table is for both admin and non-admin users(registered), and it's the booking table.(For example, registered users can book[POST] and view[GET] their bus tickets.) They cannot, however, update(PATCH) or delete ticket details on their own. The PATCH and DELETE APIs produce results for me.

I am using JWT for the authentication.

Here is the auth middleware:

```
const authentication = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.header("Authorization").replace("Bearer ", "");
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, "tokens.token": token, admin: true });

    if (!user) {
      throw new error();
    }

    req.token = token
    req.user = user
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(401).send(e);
  }
};
```

Now, all four APIs to the booking table are now only accessible by admin (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

Now I want to change it so that non-admin users(but only registered users of the app) can also access the GET and POST requests for the booking table.

That is something I am unable to do.

Here is the POST request example:

```
router.post("/bus/book", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const bookBus = new Booking(req.body);

  if(req.body.seatNumbers === Booking.seatNumbers){
    res.send('This seat is already booked')
  }
  try {
    const book = await Booking.save();
    return !book
      ? res.status(400).send("Please enter the required data")
      : res.status(201).send(book);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: When you say `non-admin user` are they users or  clients? You can provide role based access to your APIs. If the user has proper access to the path they can do it.  You can define different set of roles for each type of user and provide access to them.

Comment: Consider the following scenario: If I deploy my app online, users (typical users) will be able to access my site via ```www.something.com```. They can search for route book tickets and view their tickets . This software will also be given to my actual client. Then he'll be able to perform this action as well. The admin role and the role of a normal user are the only two roles available.

Comment: You need to differentiate the actions based on roles, I think to implement any other solution we need to understand more about the arhitecture.

Comment: sorry, I am not getting your point